# Load content within JS Spoiler only when it is opened

Tags: javascript

I currently use this spoiler code to hide things:

```html
<div class="pre-spoiler">
  <input name="Deutsch" type="button" 
  onClick="if (this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != 'none') {
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none';
  this.value = 'ButtontextSpoiler';
} else {
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'block';
  this.value = 'ButtontextSpoiler';
}" value="ButtontextSpoiler">
  <div class="spoiler" style="display: none;">
    <br>Text
  </div>
```

Only problem is:
Everything inside that spoiler code is being fetched upon pageload.

I'd like the content to be loaded *only* if the spoiler button is opened.

Is this possible somehow ?

I looked into "lazy loading", but that seems unnecessary complicated.

Writing to dom upon spoiler open seems weird too, especially as I have many lines that need to be "halted" within the spoiler tag.

Comment: It's quite easy to use ajax to fetch some html from server and insert it into an element when an event occurs. I would strongly suggest you stop writing so much javascript right in the html like that. It's very hard to manage that way. Using addEventListener rather than inline onclick will help clean it up

Comment: Well. I only use this one button. So how can this "eventListener" be used to realize your example?

Comment: A web search for tutorials on using `addEventListener` will turn up lots of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind..

I used CSS and an iFrame.

There:

```
<!---------------Newart------------------->
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;color: white;padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;position: absolute;background-color: #f1f1f1;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">RecentArt</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="0newart.html" target="iframemyart">Newart</a>
  </div>
<br>
</div>
</body>
<br><iframe src="Click_-The_Rent_Art_Menu_for_new_art" name="iframemyart" width="80%" height="500" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<!---------------Newart------------------->
```